Python: How to not need to import from my moduels like from web.web import WebConfig
I have a python app with a file tree like so
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   └── utils.py
├── files.json
├── hello.txt
├── main.py
└── web
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── utils.py
    └── web.py

In my main.py, I have to import the contents of web.py with the import statement
from web.web import *. How can I shorten this to from web import * while still keeping  web.py and utils.py in their own folder? Is there something I can edit in my __init__.py?

you can import things in web/__init__.py and your main.py will import these things when from web import *.
try this:
# main.py
from web import *

print(TEST)

# web/__init__.py
from .web import *

# web/web.py
TEST = "test"

and you will see test in the console when you run python main.py
